# error at setContentView - android.view.InflateException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image

I have a splash screen which shows a image for 2 sec. The image is a PNG image. When I start my APP sometimes it crashes with the following error messages. The exact line where my app crashes is setContentView(R.layout.splash);

key error lines :
I could see there is some error with reference to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while inflating the layout

Could you please let tell me where I need to correct my code.

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="@drawable/splash">  

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Java Code:

```
 public class Splash extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle GoOnSudha) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(GoOnSudha);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent dragDropIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.DRAGDROP");
                startActivity(dragDropIntent);
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

}
```

### LogCat:

```
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.DragDrop/com.example.DragDrop.Splash}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:255)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at com.example.DragDrop.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:18)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): ... 11 more
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): ... 23 more
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:530)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:505)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:357)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:777)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1940)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2844)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2781)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:412)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:179)
05-04 19:34:05.651: E/AndroidRuntime(28305): ... 26 more
```

Comment: What is the size of splash.png ? is it possible that it is too big for a mobile screen ?

Comment: size of image is 2.5 mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image size is too large. You app is exceeding heap size allocated for your app. Hence you will get OutofMemoryException. The heap size varies from device to device.

Scale down your bitmap or use a different image that takes less memory.

You need to load bitmaps efficiently. Check the topic under Loading scaled down version in memory.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Also load your drawable to your layout in onResume() and unbind the drawable from your layout in onPause().

Also check the video in the link below

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Answer (score 0):

2.5 mb is too big to be shown just for a few seconds. IF it is a  bitmap file, try to change to a more compressed format as they are big and take a lot of memory, For example is what Android says about images  [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

> Bitmaps take up a lot of memory, especially for rich images like photographs. For example, the camera on the Galaxy Nexus takes photos up to 2592x1936 pixels (5 megapixels). If the bitmap configuration used is ARGB_8888 (the default from the Android 2.3 onward) then loading this image into memory takes about 19MB of memory (2592*1936*4 bytes), immediately exhausting the per-app limit on some devices.